# How to create animated donut chart in plotly using R

Tags: r, plotly, tidyverse, donut-chart

I have a time series data frame and I'm trying to animate.

This is my dataframe:

```
data <- tibble(
  asset_name = c("PCC", "PCC", "PCC", "PCC", "PCC", "PCC", "pv", "pv", "pv", "pv", "pv", "pv"),
  Date_Time = c("2023-06-14 09:43:19", "2023-06-14 09:43:22", "2023-06-14 09:43:26",
                "2023-06-14 09:43:29", "2023-06-14 09:43:33", "2023-06-14 09:43:36",
                "2023-06-14 09:43:19", "2023-06-14 09:43:22", "2023-06-14 09:43:26",
                "2023-06-14 09:43:29", "2023-06-14 09:43:33", "2023-06-14 09:43:36"),
  PCC_ENERGY_IMPORTED = c(187081, 187081, 187081, 187081, 187082, 187082, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  PV_ENERGY_PRODUCED = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3425.746, 3425.746, 3425.746, 3425.769, 3425.769, 3425.769),
  TOTAL_ENERGY = c(187081, 187081, 187081, 187081, 187082, 187082, 3425.746, 3425.746, 3425.746, 3425.769, 3425.769, 3425.769)
)
```

This is my donut chart code:

```
plot <- plot_ly(
  data,
  labels = ~asset_name,
  values = ~TOTAL_ENERGY,
  type = "pie",
  hole = 0.5,
  text = ~ paste(TOTAL_ENERGY),
  textinfo = "text",
  hoverinfo = "label"
)

# Customize the donut chart
plot <- plot %>%
  layout(
    title = "Energy Contribution",
    showlegend = TRUE,
    legend = list(
      x = 1,
      y = 0.5
    )
  )

plot
```

How to make the length of the slices change based on values in each row of the dataframe. I'm thinking of taking date_time as transition
afaeg

Answer (score 1):

I have not used `plotly` but I would generate still images first. Then convert those still images into video or gif files.

#### Data

I modified values to show the changes

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
    asset_name = c("PCC", "PCC", "PCC", "PCC", "PCC", "PCC", "pv", "pv", "pv", "pv", "pv", "pv"),
    Date_Time = c("2023-06-14 09:43:19", "2023-06-14 09:43:22", "2023-06-14 09:43:26",
                  "2023-06-14 09:43:29", "2023-06-14 09:43:33", "2023-06-14 09:43:36",
                  "2023-06-14 09:43:19", "2023-06-14 09:43:22", "2023-06-14 09:43:26",
                  "2023-06-14 09:43:29", "2023-06-14 09:43:33", "2023-06-14 09:43:36"),
    PCC_ENERGY_IMPORTED = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    PV_ENERGY_PRODUCED = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
    TOTAL_ENERGY = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15)
)
```

Use your code in a function:

```
plot_this <- function() {
  plot_ly(
          df,
          labels = ~asset_name,
          values = ~TOTAL_ENERGY,
          type = "pie",
          hole = 0.5,
          text = ~ paste(TOTAL_ENERGY),
          textinfo = "text",
          hoverinfo = "label"
      ) %>% 
      layout(
          title = "Energy Contribution",
          showlegend = TRUE,
          legend = list(
              x = 1,
              y = 0.5
          )
      )
}

time_list <- data$Date_Time %>% unique()
img_list <- paste0("img_", seq_along(time_list), ".jpg")

for (i in seq_along(time_list)) {
    df <- data %>% 
        filter(Date_Time == time_list[i])
    fig <- plot_this()
    save_image(p = fig, file = img_list[i]) 
}

av::av_encode_video(img_list, "output.gif")
```

[image]

Comment: can this be put into shiny?

Comment: I don't have much experience with `shiny`, but I think it is possible to add images or videos to shiny.